# What is the most common practice of generating (X,Y) from an arbitrary CDF or PDF?

Tags: r, probability, sampling, monte-carlo

[image: generate]

So I can generate `X` from arbitrary CDF **F(x)** by the procedure above. Can it be generalized to two variables? How, exactly? If not, what's the best way to generate `(X,Y)` from arbitrary CDF **F(x,y)** or PDF **f(x,y)**?

[image: X,Y]

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in the field but I can imagine 3 different cases :

- Variables are **independent** in which case you can use your formula on each
- You have access to some **chain rules decomposition** that allows you to easily generate each variable one at a time using your formula
- If none of the above : https://appsilon.com/how-to-sample-from-multidimensional-distributions-using-gibbs-sampling/